# Heroku Search Broken - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I've recently pushed a Rails 3.1 App to heroku. Locally, everything works fine, but in the live app, the search functionality is broken.

**Model:**

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
```

end

**View:**

```
<%= form_tag apps_path, :method => 'get', :id => "search" do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "search-button" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
    @apps = App.search(params[:search])
    @number_of_apps = @apps.count
end
```

I have a feeling that it has to do with the fact that my local setup runs on SQLite3 and the Heroku setup uses PostgreSQL.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that Postgres like matching is case-sensitive. Try using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: which reaffirms one of my mantras - Develop against the same DB platform that you will be deploying to! Or at least test against it before deploying.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice :) It worked, would you recommend any specific gems for more advanced search functionality?

Comment: You should have a look at [Postgres Full Text Search capabilities](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html)

Comment: If you will have to search through multiple fields and large number of records, Heroku supports [Websolr](http://addons.heroku.com/websolr), which in my experience, is quite efficient.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

1. PostgreSQL `LIKE` keyword is different than `LIKE` in SQLite. `LIKE` in SQLite is `ILIKE` in PostgreSQL. Either use the right keyword or downcase the comparison.
2. `find(:all)` has been deprecated since 2.3 and should have been removed in 3.1. Please use the `#all` method.

   ```
   def self.search(query)
     if query
       where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%").all
     else
       all
     end
   end
   ```

   Even better, return a scope to take advantage of lazy loading.

   ```
   def self.search(query)
     if query
       where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%")
     else
       self
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Texticle gem](http://tenderlove.github.com/texticle/). It's very easy to install and works wonderfully with Heroku, but you need to use PostgreSQL.